# Cannont parse XML (empty info and not expected output)

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-requests

I am want to extract some weather prediction info from [here](http://%20http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_28079.xml).

I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` and requests to do this in python 3.6 (Windows).

I cannot get the output I expect, sometimes info appears as None and sometimes it is no the correct info.

**This is my code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


url = "http://www.aemet.es/xml/municipios/localidad_28079.xml"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}

result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

root = ET.fromstring(result.text)
hoy = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

previsiones = {'00-24':'','00-12':'','00-06':'','06-12':'','12-18':'','18-24':''} # I will save here the info latter

for dia in root.iter('dia'):
    fecha = dia.attrib['fecha']
    if fecha == hoy:
        prevs = dia.findall('viento')
        for prev in prevs:
            horas = prev.attrib['periodo']
            print("Fecha:",fecha)
            print("Periodo:",horas)
            print("Direccion:",prev.find('direccion').text)
            print("Velocidad",prev.find('velocidad').text)
```

**This is the output:**

```
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 00-24
Direccion: None
Velocidad None
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 00-12
Direccion: None
Velocidad None
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 12-24
Direccion: O
Velocidad 25
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 00-06
Direccion: SO
Velocidad 10
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 06-12
Direccion: SO
Velocidad 25
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 12-18
Direccion: O
Velocidad 25
Fecha: 2019-06-14
Periodo: 18-24
Direccion: O
Velocidad 15
```

**This is the output expected:**

```
Fecha: 2019-06-06
Periodo: 12-24
Direccion: SO
Velocidad: 30

# And so on with each time period (Periodo)
```

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the expected result ? the <prediccion> element has no attribute, thus the "attrib" property is an empty mapping. Nothing abnormal !

Comment: You could try a simple xml parser called untangle or xmltodict. Here is a nice tutorial: https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/xml/

Answer (score 1):

```
for prediccion in root.iter('prediccion'):
    print(prediccion.attrib)
```

For some reason you are printing the attributes of each `prediccion` node and there are none, hence the empty dictionary.

Instead print the node itself.

```
for prediccion in root.iter('prediccion'):
   print(prediccion)
```

Outputs

```
<Element 'prediccion' at 0x000002517A629A48>
```